# How to replace stuff in a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `$text` and want to modify it with a regex. The string contains multiple sections like `<NAME>John</NAME>`.

I want to search for those sections, which I would normally do with something like

```
$text =~ m/<NAME>(.*?)<\/NAME>/g
```

but then make sure that there are no leading and trailing blanks and no leading non-word characters, which I would normally ensure with something like

```
$temp =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # trim leading and trailing whitespaces
$temp = s/^\W*//g; # remove all leading non-word chars
```

Now my question is: How do I actually make this happen? Is it possible to use a `s///` regex instead of the `m//`?

Comment: If you have a variable containing XML data then you must process it using a proper XML parser like [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) or 
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML). Regular expressions won't work. You may think they do, but one day your data will change and your program will fail without you noticing.

Comment: You forgot to mention what you want to replace. The word inside `<NAME>`?

Comment: What I want to replace is whatever is between <NAME> and </NAME>.
And this is the only kind of tags that appear in the overall string, so I don't want to use a big XML machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is merely "clean up" the text inside the tag (insofar as it's possible to "parse" XML using regular expressions). This should do the trick:

```
$text =~ s/(<NAME>)\s*\W*(.*?)\s*(<\/NAME>)/$1$2$3/sgi;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in a single substitution, but it's unnecessarily complex. I suggest you do a two-tier substitution using a *executable replacement*.

```
my $text = '<NAME>   %^John^%

</NAME>';

$text =~ s{ (?<=<NAME>) ([^<>]*) (?=</NAME>) }{
  (my $new = $1) =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//g;
  $new =~ s/\A\W+//;
  $new;
}eg;

print $text;
```

**output**

```
<NAME>John^%</NAME>
```

This is even simpler if you have version 14 or later of Perl 5, and want to use the *non-destructive* ( `/r` modifier) substitution mode.

```
$text =~ s{ (?<=<NAME>) ([^<>]*) (?=</NAME>) }{ $1 =~ s/\A\s+|\s+\z//gr =~ s/\A\W+//r }exg;
```

Comment: Hi Borodin, this looks great, but on Strawberry Perl 5.20.1. it outputs the original string without anything being replaced...
Also, can you enlighten me what the ?= in the first and last grouping in the regex do? Thanks!

Comment: @user1769925: Did you read my warning about processing XML with regexes? Those are [*look-around assertions*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns). The pattern matches a sequence of any characters other than angle brackets `<>` that is immediately *preceded* by `<NAME>` and immediately *followed* by `</NAME>`. Did you try running my first block of code on its own? Did you get the same result as I did? Which variation of the substitution isn't working for you?

Comment: Thanks for that info, now I understand the look ahead/behind; but the code actually does not seem to substitute anything on my machine, it just outputs $text unchanged; the solution below, which solves it using groups actually works for me